# Kendo/Angular - ng-disabled in IE10

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am encountering a problem with ng-disabled in IE10 with Kendo UI buttons, combo boxes, drop down lists, date pickers, and numeric text boxes.

Everything works fine in IE11, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, but IE10 doesn't seem to respond to changes in the models.

Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating the issue with Kendo buttons (it doesn't work in IE10) ... http://jsfiddle.net/lejuan5150/ba2djbgg

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-app="app">

<div data-ng-controller="personController">    

    <kendo-button 
        id="btnAddNew" 
        class="k-primary" 
        ng-click="doAddNew()" 
        data-ng-disabled="editing"
    >Add New</kendo-button>

    <kendo-button 
        id="btnSave" 
        class="k-primary" 
        ng-click="doSave()" 
        data-ng-disabled="!editing"
    >Save</kendo-button>

    <kendo-button 
        id="btnDelete" 
        class="k-primary" 
        ng-click="doDelete()" 
        data-ng-disabled="!editing"
    >Delete</kendo-button>        

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular
    .module("app", [ 
        "kendo.directives"
]);

app.controller("personController", [
    "$scope",
    personController
]);

function personController(
    $scope
){
    init();

    function init(){    
        $scope.editing = false;
    }    

    $scope.doAddNew = function(){
        $scope.editing = true;
    }

    $scope.doSave = function(){
        $scope.editing = false;
    }    

    $scope.doDelete = function(){
        $scope.editing = false;
    }        
}
```

Is this a known problem and is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

I dug deeper into @leJuan5150's answer, and something on that site is promising. After reviewing [webcomponents.js](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/) and what it did, I downloaded the [prebuilt](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/releases) script and tested it. **This fixed IE10** but after fully deploying it (from [nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WebComponentJS/)) **other Kendo controls broke** across multiple browsers. We were getting errors inside jQuery.js, like "SCRIPT5022: HierarchyRequestError" (in IE10 & IE11) and "TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node" (in FireFox).

I replaced webcomponents.js with **webcomponents-lite.js** and the issues are reported **resolved** (Chrome, FireFox, IE10, IE11).

Answer (score -1):

Telerik support helped me out with this.  They pointed me to the polyfills at http://webcomponents.org/ because Kendo/Angular uses mutation observers which are not supported in IE10. Worked like a charm.

Comment: What worked like a charm? That link takes me to "a place to discuss and evolve Web Component best-practices" but I did not see a implementable solution.